# TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int' in version numbers

Tags: python-3.x, list, version

I have the following code which throws an error, I don't understand why it's happening, if you change the item '2.0.8' to '2.1.8' the error goes away. even if you change the item '2.0.8' to '3.1.8' it will work fine, any suggestions?

```
from distutils.version import LooseVersion
versions_list = ['2.5.6.RC02', '2.0.8', '2.0-m2']
versions_list.sort(key=LooseVersion, reverse=False)

print(versions_list)
```

TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeah. The 1st one isn't relevant -- the last two are sufficient to demonstrate the problem.

```
sorted(['2.1.8', '2.1-m2'], key=LooseVersion)  # fails
sorted(['8', 'm2'], key=LooseVersion)  # fails
```

One way to interpret `TypeError` is "the two versions are not comparable", that is,
it's undefined whether one or the other should come first.

We're doing three comparisons:
`2 == 2`, `1 == 1`, and finally we wonder how `8` compares with `'m2'`.
That last one is where things fall apart.
Notice that we don't compare in ASCII order,
since we *really* want `9 < 11` rather than the other way around.
Integer comparisons are quite different from string comparisons.
When you adjusted it to show `0` or `1` in the middle,
you were short circuiting the comparison procedure,
allowing it to report an answer before inspecting all components.

If catching `TypeError` and reporting "indeterminate" is not good enough for you,
then I suppose I would counsel cleaning up the version components
prior to handing them to `LooseVersion`.

Comment: Good catch, cleaning up the version components sounds reasonable.